# AWS VPN Connection

Tags: amazon-vpc

I got notification from *aws Customer vpn* connection issues

> You have new non-redundant VPN connections One or more of your vpn
>   connections are not using both tunnels. This mode of operation is not
>   highly available and we strongly recommend you configure your second
>   tunnel. View your non redundant VPN connections.

Any suggestions for these issues?

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore this warning your tunnels are redundant.

A single AWS VPN connection has two tunnels. AWS VPN automatically fails over to the second tunnel in case of maintenance or failure.

The reason you are getting that error is that both peer ips are not up simultaneously some devices give you this ability such as cisco ASA running in Active/Active (Be sure to use asymmetric routing if this is the case).

[AWS VPN Knowledge center](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpn-fault-tolerance/)